# C# generic constraints issue

Tags: c#, .net, generics

Can I propagate generic constraints on derived types that are declared in base class in C# ?

Example Program displays error :

> *The type 'T' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type
>   or method 'Test.Base'. There is no boxing conversion or type parameter
>   conversion from 'T' to 'Test.IBase'.*

```
interface IBase
{

}

class Base<T> where T : IBase
{


}

class Derived<T> : Base<T>
{

}
```

Comment: I have already applied, but there is mistake in html formatting. so please check it again.

Answer (score 4):

```
class Derived<T> : Base<T> where T : IBase
{

}
```

Comment: This is repeat task that I have already done on base class. In C++ this is possible. Doesn't C# provide any trick for that ?

Comment: Unfortunately, in C# you should always define constraints in derived types.

Answer (score 1):

In your `Derived<T>` class you haven't specified that `T` has to implement `IBase` and because it's used in as a type parameter in `Base<T>` you can't say any `T` can be used. Change it to this:

```
class Derived<T> : Base<T> where T : IBase
```

Comment: This is repeat task that I have already done on base class. In C++ this is possible. Doesn't C# provide any trick for that ?

Comment: It's another T, you still have to constraint it; it doesn't know it's the same T as the base class.

Comment: @RajdipPatel: What L-Three said. Think of the `T` as a parameter for a method. Just because 2 parameters for methods are named the same doesn't mean they refer to the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Should be:

```
class Derived<T> : Base<T> where T : IBase
{

}
```

Always explicitly put your constraints, because T is just a declaration, it's not the same T as the one in your base class.